# How to find the Polynomial associated with $det(A-\lambda I)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I have trouble understanding how they got the polynomial circled in red. I tried to factor but it didn't give me the same thing.

Comment: Set $x=-\lambda -1$ in the original matrix to simplify the arithmetic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $x=1$ is a root of $x^3-3x+2$, hence $x^3-3x+2=(x-1)(x^2+x-2)=(x-1)^2(x+2)$.

Therefore, as per the blue part, $$\det(A-\lambda I)=(-1-\lambda-1)^2(-1-\lambda+2)=(\lambda+2)^2(1-\lambda)$$

Comment: The official answer is -( - 1)( + 2)^2. How come you have something a little different, how can obtain the official answer?

Comment: Obviously, $-(\lambda-1)=(1-\lambda)$.

Comment: Ah ok I see it now, thx

Answer (score 0):

Apply the rule of Sarrus to get $$p_A(\lambda)=(-1-\lambda)^3+1+1-(-1-\lambda)-(-1-\lambda)-(-1-\lambda)=(-1-\lambda)^3+3\lambda+5=(1-\lambda)(\lambda+2)^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

An idea: in the definition of $\;P_A(\lambda)\;$ , sum columns 2,3 to column 1 and then make zeros down the first column:

$$P_A(\lambda)=\begin{vmatrix}-(\lambda-1)&1&1\\
-(\lambda-1)&-(\lambda+1)&1\\
-(\lambda+1)&1&-(\lambda+1)\end{vmatrix}\stackrel{R_k-R_1, k=2,3}=\begin{vmatrix}-(\lambda-1)&1&1\\
0&-(\lambda+2)&0\\
0&0&-(\lambda+2)\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$=-(\lambda-1)(\lambda+2)^2$$